# Updating HTML table using Jquery & ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update table data without refreshing the page using Ajax and Jquery.

I know I will need `setInterval()` method, because I want the table to be refreshed to all users, because multiple users could insert data in to the database and I want to update the table to every user.

I have made a script to send the data from a form without redirecting the user or refreshing the page and then insert it in the database.

MyScript.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "Ready!" );
    //Submitting from data
    $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){
        if($('#fName').val() && $('#lName').val() && $('#nickname').val()) {
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "process.php",
               data: $("#submitForm").serialize(),
               success: function(data){
                   console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });
         }
         else {
             alert("Please fill the fields.")
         }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In my `process.php` file I insert the data to the database.

Now I have `info.php` file that generates my table with all the data and I have a form there to insert new data.

```
<div id="table" class="col-md-7 ml-5">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php $user->showUsers(); ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

the `showUsers()` function just generate the other rows of the table with the data from SQL.

I have no idea how to refresh the table using Jquery and Ajax.
I tried to use the `.load()` method, but it also generates the html for my form.

Please help.

Comment: You might actually be over-thinking the issue. All you need on your AJAX backend is to generate a data structure (like in a JSON format) that is passed back to the page itself. The jQuery code on the page itself should handle how the new rows are inserted into the pre-existing table.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can use setInterval or better setTimeout since you want the return of the data to trigger a new request later

```
var tId="";
function getInfo() {
  $.get("info.php #table",function(data) {
    tId = setTimeout(getInfo,60000);
    $("#someContainer").append(data);
  });
}
getInfo();
```

Comment: Hello I tried your snippet, but it generates the whole HTML code from `info.php` and in that file I have a lot of HTML elements, it's not just the table I have forms and divs. It put's all that HTML content in to the div that I target. Can I somehow get only the HTML content of the div in which I have table in and display that HTML in the div I target.

Comment: You mean       $.get("info.php #table"

Comment: @mlungjan
Yes exactly! I tried `$.get("info.php #table")` but it's still getting all the html and not the html that is inside a div with id="table"

Comment: Perhaps there are more than one #table ID on the page